# Adding very simple speech recognition ability to my iphone/ipad application

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition

I want to implement 10 words speech recognition to my iphone/ipad program.

I just want to let user to record 10 voice records (2 sec long each) and let the program run commands when ever it hears and recognise one of those words.

it look pretty simple to me. But don't know which speech recognition kit can help me most

Thank you.

Comment: [my quite popular creature](http://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec), [another opensource approach](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) - which one did Google not give you a link to?

Comment: Dear carbonic acyd. Thanks for great help. But I only have a question after your comment in my mind. Can we use google speech api in our apple aplications or not? Because it is not officialy opened to publicity and I don't know how apple reacts theese kind of applications